# How to open and edit a file in the command line?

Tags: command-line

I am new to creating files from the command line and I've been following LearnFHIR, and I've made some files in the directory. How do I open and edit/save them?

C:\Users\jsmith\patient-todo\client>

and I made the files using type nul>main.html

Comment: I believe Windows default editor is Notepad.  So, try with `notepad path/filename`

Comment: StackOverflow is concerned with programming code issues. For beginner problems not related to programming code, you should post to https://superuser.com. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: How do I open them in the terminal?

Comment: The terminal is for running commands.  You cannot directly edit a file in the terminal.  You start a program (an editor in this case, such as Notepad) that itself does the editing.

Answer (score 0):

You can not edit, but can read from command line.

`$` cd C:\Users\jsmith\patient-todo\client

`$` ls

`$` cat your_filename

`$` vi your_filename